# .htaccess, RewriteRule add string at the end

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With that code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^www.edutic\.ch [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) www.emitic.ch/new/$1 [L,R=301]

www.edutic.ch/?p=1767
```

becomes

```
www.emitic.ch/new/?p=1767
```

But I need to add:   `&option=com_wordpress&Itemid=143` at the end.

I want

```
www.edutic.ch/?p=1767
```

to become

```
www.emitic.ch/new/?p=1767&option=com_wordpress&Itemid=143
```

How should I change my rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.edutic\.ch$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.emitic.ch/new/$1?&option=com_wordpress&Itemid=143 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.